# Scraping IMDb user reviews using R, only got the first review back

Tags: r, web-scraping, r-markdown

I'm new to web scraping and hoping to use it for sentimental analysis. Here's the code I used, and it'd only returned with the first review...thanks in advance!

```
library(rvest)
library(XML)
library(plyr)
HouseofCards_IMDb <- read_html("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1856010/reviews?ref_=tt_urv")

#Used SelectorGadget as the CSS Selector
reviews <- HouseofCards_IMDb %>% html_nodes("#pagecontent") %>%
html_nodes("div+p") %>%
html_text()

#perfrom data cleaning on user reviews
reviews <- gsub("\r?\n|\r", " ", reviews) 
reviews <- tolower(gsub("[^[:alnum:] ]", " ", reviews))
reviews <- paste(reviews, collapse = "") 
print(reviews)
write(reviews, "IMDb.CSV")
```

Comment: Your query is correct, reviews is returning 10 reviews for the page.  The line: "paste(reviews, collapse = "")" is compressing all 10 into 1 long comment.  Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @Dave2e Awh thanks for pointing it out! One user wrote up several paragraphs in one comment section and I thought the line : "paste(reviews, collapse = "")" will only compress his paragraphs into one... I was trying to is to return all the reviews in one function, and then makes sure that multiple paragraphs from one user is compressed into one comment section.

Answer (score 0):

By F12 of Chromium, the XPath of the second review is:
//*[@id="tn15content"]/p[2]/text()

And the third review is:
//*[@id="tn15content"]/p[5]/text()[1]

You can use XML::htmlParse function to parse the page and XML::xpathSApply function to extract to correct nodes of the DOM (apparently, for review texts this is

//*[@id="tn15content"]/p/text()